# Users cannot access Search Results Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, permissions, search-results

We have a dummy account for testing our production SharePoint Intranet. I gave the account read permission in the search center and read permission in the site collection "Purchasing Department" I created a custom search results page in the search center called "PurchasingSearch" which has a couple of custom refiners, custom display template, and custom result source. I created a search web part on the home page of "Purchasing Department" which redirects searches to the "PurchasingSearch" page.

Ok, now here is the problem, when I type in a keyword in the web part, it redirects me to PurchasingSearch page, but there are not results, just a message that says "Sorry Something went wrong". If I click on one of the other Search Sources in the search navigation such as "Everything" or "People" or "Conversations", results start to populate.

I do not understand what the problem can be since my dummy account has permission and access to both the search center and the site collection.

By the way I am an adminstrator and using my account I have no problems using the "PurchasingSearch" Page.

Any help or Advice will be appreciated???

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out that the html for the "PurchasingSearch" page was not published. Both the .js and the .html need to be published.

Comment: Sorry for wasting anybody's time